# How to get PushKey from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

i want to get the PushKey that i got from executing this line:

```
var id = reference.push().key
reference.child(id!!).setValue(value)
```

The Example of the PushKey :

> -MZxHIafETe10OiOuR2J

I already tried with lots of tutor in internet to get the PUSH_KEY but none of them is worked for mine.

My JSON :
[JSON Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHIwh.png)

My Code : [Source Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4ps3.png)

```
var query = reference.orderByChild("nik").equalTo(induk)
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

            var a = reference.ref.key
            println(a) // returns  "https://xxx.asia 
                   southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/Users"

            for (userSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                     //execute code 
               }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the key of the of the snapshot that triggered your `onDataChange`, that'd be:

```
dataSnapshot.ref.key
```

Since you do a query, you'll need a loop through as shown in the documentation on [listening for a value event on a list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events):

```
for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
    // use snapshot.ref.key to access the key
```